# Use CGI to Run Scripts that Modify Files

Tags: apache, cgi

I've just started using CGI with Apache and am able to generate dynamic web pages. However I would like to be able to run scripts on my server that modify files as opposed to just echoing back text.

For example consider the script `create.cgi`

```
#!/bin/bash

touch example
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "Creating Example File"

exit 0
```

If I run this on my server then the file `example` is created, however if it is called using CGI through a webpage, it does not create `example`. Why is this and how can I get around it?

Comment: Apache will run as it's own user - make sure that user has permissions to the directory where you're attempting to create the file

Comment: Ok, cool this works. I'll accept as an answer if you want to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache will run as it's own user - make sure that user has permissions to the directory where you're attempting to create the file.